# Excel 365 - ISNA function not recognizing #N/A cells

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to figure out where I went wrong here. Basically `B2` is a status column. Column B uses a `vlookup` of an ID in column A to pull back that status. If a status is not retrieved then the cell is listed as `#N/A`.

Column C uses the formula in the code section to check the status and perform different vlookups based on the status.

The final IF(ISNA(B2),"Not Found in MI","In MI - not mapped yet") function is not behaving properly.

> I have tried:
>   ISNA
>   ISBLANK
>   ISERR
>   ISERROR

And a few other IS functions I can't remember off the top of my head.

`=IF(B2="Mapped",VLOOKUP(A2,scheme!A:C,3,FALSE),IF(B2="Unmappable",VLOOKUP(A2,umaps!A:C,3,FALSE),IF(ISNA(B2),"Not Found in MI","In MI - not mapped yet")))`

Status of `#N/A` is expected some times, I would just rather have it say something like "Not Found", which I can then trigger conditional formatting off of to highlight the entire row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess would be that your `#N/A` in cell `B2` is not really an error, but a text value. For example:

[image]

If that's the case, then I'd suggest modifying your original formula to do the following:

```
=IF(OR(ISNA(B2),B2="#N/A"),"Not Found in MI","In MI - not mapped yet")
```

**Edit:**

The issue with your original formula is that when B2 is a true error, the first check (i.e. `=IF(B2="Mapped",...`) would evaluate to `#N/A` and the formula won't proceed further.

Because B2 is equal to `#N/A`, the first check evaluates to `=IF(#N/A="Mapped",`, which is equal to `IF(#N/A,...` and that's where the formula stops (final result = `#N/A`). You can see these steps in Formulas > `Evaluate Formula` option - click `Evaluate` button 2-3 times to see the calculation mechanism.

[image]

In order to fix this issue, we need to re-arrange your formula a little bit, i.e. `ISNA` check needs to be moved to the very beginning:

```
=IF(ISNA(B2),"Not Found in MI",IF(B2="Mapped",VLOOKUP(A2,scheme!A:C,3,FALSE),IF(B2="Unmappable",VLOOKUP(A2,umaps!A:C,3,FALSE),"In MI - not mapped yet")))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edits in my original post and the suggestion.

I think that this screenshot indicates this really is a value not available error. (Sorry having trouble figuring out how to add an image, looks like I have to host it elsewhere.

  [1]: https://imgur.com/a/RBw070h

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RBw070h - sorry can't figure out how this formatting works inline. That screenshot should indicate this really is an error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot! Huh that's weird. Can you tell me what is the result of `=ISNA(B2)` and also what kind of formula you have in cell B2, plus what is the cell's formatting (is it General? Text? Custom?).

Comment: Ahh ignore me @Robbie Harris, I'm talking rubbish. I know what the issue is - I'll update my answer right now.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that but I just couldn't work it out in my head once I got to the third IF function.

In the context of my spreadsheet this makes blank lines also appear as "Not Found". So I added a check to the cell to see if the ID is blank before the ISNA check and if it is output "No ID Provided". 

`=IF(ISBLANK(A11),"No MATID Provided",IF(ISNA(B11),"Not Found in MI",IF(B11="Mapped",VLOOKUP(A11,scheme!A:C,3,FALSE),IF(B11="Unmappable",VLOOKUP(A11,umaps!A:C,3,FALSE),"In MI - not mapped yet"))))`

Thanks so much!